# .NET Core / EF Core (SQL) Max Pool issue when using (Hosted) Background Service

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.0

My team and I have been experiencing some EF Core / SQL pooling issues on a high utilization .NET Core Web App.

`Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.`

The issue started occurring when EF Core / ApplicationDbContext was being referenced in a Background task on a hosted service (QueuedHostedService). Following the guide at:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

I've followed the recommended dependency injection and hosted service guides.

#### Steps to reproduce

The relevant lines:

Startup.cs

```
...
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

...

services.AddScoped<IScopedWorker, ScopedWorker>();
services.AddSingleton<MySingletonThatAddsToBackground>();
// Follow the host service guide from microsoft.
services.AddHostedService<QueuedHostedService>();
services.AddSingleton<IBackgroundTaskQueue, BackgroundTaskQueue>();
```

MySingletonThatAddsToBackground.cs

```
public class MySingletonThatAddsToBackground
{
    private readonly IBackgroundTaskQueue _taskQueue;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly CancellationToken _cancellationToken;
    public IServiceProvider _services { get; }

    public MySingletonThatAddsToBackground(IServiceProvider services, IBackgroundTaskQueue taskQueue,
        ILogger<MonitorLoop> logger,
        IHostApplicationLifetime applicationLifetime)
    {
        _services = services;
        _taskQueue = taskQueue;
        _logger = logger;
        _cancellationToken = applicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping;
    }

    public void DoWorkBackground()
    {
        // Enqueue a background work item
        _taskQueue.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(async token =>
        {
            try
            {
                using (var scope = _services.CreateScope())
                {
                    var scopedWorker = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IScopedWorker>();

                    await scopedWorker.DoWork();
                }
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
                // Prevent throwing if the Delay is cancelled
            }
        });
    }
}
```

ScopedWorker.cs

```
public class ScopedWorker : IScopedWorker
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

    public ScopedWorker(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public void DoWork()
    {
        var customers = _db.MyCustomers.ToListAsync();

        // Do stuff to customers.

        await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

#### Discussion

Inside MySingletonThatAddsToBackground, after the `using (var scope)` is completed, shouldn't the scope be disposed, which then disposes `ScopedWorker` (scoped), which then disposes the `ApplicationDbConext` (scoped), and then closes the connection / pool connection?

Is there something I'm not implementing properly to cause the connection pool leak?

#### Further technical details

EF Core version: 3.1.4
Database provider: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
Target framework: .NET Core 3.1.4
Operating system: Windows Server 2016, SQL Server 2016
IDE: 16.6

Comment: The article you used contains an example, not a recommended way of working. How are the "jobs" posted in that queue processed? One at a time? Many of them concurrently? What does your `ExecuteAsync` do? Do you really need a *job* queue, or could you just post messages to the queue and let `ExecuteAsync` process them one by one? If your background service performs a single job, there's no reason for the complexity of a job queue.

Comment: The problem with the "job queue" is that half of the processing code lives in your singleton and half in the background service. Making a change in one, affect how the other works. The problem is almost certainly in the code you *didn't* post.

Comment: This exact issue has been provided to EF Core issue tracker - [EF Core SQL Max Pool issue when using (Hosted) Background Service #21270
 Closed](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/21270). They didn't find anything in the provided code which could be causing it, so do I. Since apparently the issue is caused by unknown code not shown here, the question is unanswerable.

Comment: Considering the pooling works in Round Robin cycle, and in the scope inner the generate independly threads (by `async`/`await`) that not completely ends when starts next last Thread, it is very probally scope is not disposing when the last Thread starts (thinking in a long time of execution).

Answer (score -1):

I read [this article](https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) recently (at ASP.NET Monsters) and I think this can help for your case: Please, try to monitoring the Background Service using `NETSTAT` and look the `State` of each request; in article contains more explained detailing, but, in resuming, problems associate a erroneous behavior at Garbage Dispose routine, that impacts the ends of HTTP Pipeline establishment.

In other words, check (by `NESTAT`) if `State` is different of `ESTABLISHED`; if it's occurs, you'll get the root cause and will need to change your code approach, being careful about using garbage collection.